# Plone: Howto add a new SecurityPolicy

Tags: plone

I like to modify (by subclassing) the Plone `SecurityPolicy` (I like to introduce negative permissions but that is not the point of my question) and find no way in doing so.

There is a property in `etc/site.zcml` called `securityPolicy` pointing to `AccessControl.security.SecurityPolicy`. But nether that class nor its ancestor is called. Instead `AccessControl.ImplPython.ZopeSecurityPolicy` is called by the cImplementation when checking for security. There is a lame comment on that in the code but not more.

If one changes `etc/site.zcml` and points it to a custom `SecurityPolicy` the policy is registered in the global variable `_defaultPolicy` but in effect nothing changed. Also a call to `setSecurityPolicy` (e.g. triggered by a `zope.processlifetime.IProcessStarting`) changes the global but with no effect.

So the question still stands out: Howto modify the Plone SecurityPolicy?

Please no recommendations and discussion on WHY I like to change the security policy and if it is necessary. I have grown up with the zope3 security system and like to have more of it in plone. Just give me a handle.

Comment: Can't answer to your main question (too deep inside the Zope 2 stuff) but "negative" permissions has already been implemented. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.subtractiveworkflow/
Maybe there you can also find some implementation detail

Comment: I would put a ipdb breakpoint to `setSecurityPolicy` to discover all call sites where it is called, then monkey patch the right one to call it with your custom policy